# TL431 on-mode voltage

Tags: tl431

The [TL431 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf) mentions that the V<sub>IKA</sub> is approximately 2 volts (when the input is more than V<sub>ref</sub> = 2.5 V), but based on my simulation, it shows me (1.07 V to 1.2 V). I need to know where I can find the V<sub>KA</sub> on-voltage based on the datasheet.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Re *"V_IKA"*: Don't you mean *"V_KA"*? ([Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf))

Answer (score 7):

It's not specified and it's not important in most applications. It just has to be reliably well under 2.5V over process variation and temperature.

Looks like (from the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf?)) it has to be at least two diode drops based on the shunt transistor actually being a Darlington pair.

[image]

You can measure an actual sample, however it may vary somewhat between manufacturers and from unit-to-unit, so it's not really something you should depend on to an any degree of confidence. It will also certainly vary with temperature.

---

Just to indicate some differences- a simulation in LTspice with the 'TL431' model gives ~1.1V and a simulation with the TL431A model gives ~1.8V.

Comment: 1V is clearly a simulation "error" not a process variation.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Oh, I made a classic mA/µA mixup when reading it..